# Drools and Multithreading

Tags: drools

I am executing Drools in a multi-threaded application. Often times, I am seeing this warning in the console:

**2018-01-24 09:17:16.223 AM [drools-worker-4] WARN  o.d.c.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint - Exception jitting**: driveable == 'Y' This is NOT an error and NOT prevent the correct execution since the constraint will be evaluated in intrepreted mode.

Does it mean the constraint order for evaluation needs to be changed? Any insights on this will be helpful.
I am using Drools 6.5.0.Final.
Application: Spring Boot with Thread pool task executor.

Answer (score 0):

KSession is not thread safe. Behavior is unpredictable in multi-threaded app.

So option # 1: Make it thread local. Do not forget to retract all facts after fireAllRules()

Option # 2: Create new KSession each time in order to fireAllRules(). Do not forget to dispose it afterwards.